# Download Python packages with correct dependencies for offline install

Tags: python, pip, airflow

I am trying to install Apache Airflow 2.7.3 offline.
I have read about `pip download`, requirement file, constraint file but still not able to do this.

Below is my full script to demonstrate the problem.

```
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.7.3
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-$AIRFLOW_VERSION/constraints-$PYTHON_VERSION.txt"

# download constraint file locally to be referred to later
curl -L $CONSTRAINT_URL --output constraints-$AIRFLOW_VERSION-$PYTHON_VERSION.txt

# create a folder to store downloaded packages
mkdir pip-download && cd pip-download

# pip download packages with constraints
pip download "apache-airflow==$AIRFLOW_VERSION" --constraint ../constraints-$AIRFLOW_VERSION-$PYTHON_VERSION.txt      

# pip install packages locally with constraints
pip install apache-airflow==$AIRFLOW_VERSION --no-index --find-links=. --constraint ../constraints-$AIRFLOW_VERSION-$PYTHON_VERSION.txt
```

However, running this will results in the following error

```
Processing ./connexion-2.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from apache-airflow==2.7.3)
Processing ./cron_descriptor-1.4.0.tar.gz (from apache-airflow==2.7.3)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      Looking in links: .
      Processing ./setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
(env) [airflow@89a126f62807 airflow]$
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that installing with the following command would work.

```
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.7.3
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-$AIRFLOW_VERSION/constraints-$PYTHON_VERSION.txt"
pip install apache-airflow==$AIRFLOW_VERSION --constraint $CONSTRAINT_URL
```

Testing

```
(env) [airflow@89a126f62807 airflow]$ airflow version
2.7.3
(env) [airflow@89a126f62807 airflow]$
```

Comment: Your first batch of commands (`pip install apache-airflow==$AIRFLOW_VERSION --no-index --find-links=.`) works for me. Debian 12, Python 3.8.

Comment: Also works with Python 3.9. But not with 3.10 and 3.11. The error is similar but about different package: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement poetry-core>=1.0.0a9 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for poetry-core>=1.0.0a9" I added the absent package to `pip download` and installed `apache-airflow` under Python 3.9 and 3.10. So my advice: add `wheel` to the commandline: `pip download "apache-airflow==$AIRFLOW_VERSION" wheel --constraint ../constraints-$AIRFLOW_VERSION-$PYTHON_VERSION.txt`

Comment: I would create a venv Install All Things and move that to offline machine